# Force an application's traffic through a SOCKS proxy

Tags: proxy, application, socks5-proxy

How can the TCP traffic initiated by a specific application be forced to go through a SOCKS proxy, regardless of the remote IP or port?

A VPN would direct *all* outbound traffic on a host through an interface (`tun0` typically), so it's an overkill solution. But in a split tunnel configuration, instead of doing that by default, the VPN client offers a SOCKS proxy for specific applications. While browsers support connecting through a SOCKS proxy, many other applications don't.

I've tried [dante socksify](https://www.inet.no/dante/doc/latest/config/client.html) but it didn't work with common programs like `curl` and `wget`. (I've sent a message to their mailing list, but it's [not archived anywhere](https://www.inet.no/dante/support.html) so I can't link to it.)

Comment: use [tsocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wikipedia lists a number of [open-source proxifiers](https://web.archive.org/web/20171020003229/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_proxifiers). Of those, `proxychains-ng` seems to be [the most actively developed](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng), judging by GitHub activity.

To install and configure,

1. Download the [latest release](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng/releases)
2. Unzip and `cd` into the directory
3. `./configure && make`
4. Optional: `sudo make install && sudo make install-config`
5. `nano /usr/local/etc/proxychains.conf`
6. At the end of the config file, set the SOCKS IP port address

Usage:

```
proxychains4 -q curl icanhazip.com
```

Comment: seems cool from that tool we could develop a gui to mimic proxifier on windows

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative solution:**

**[Proxybound](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Proxy/Proxybound)** can do the job

```
proxybound application-command
```

**Note**: I am the developer of this program.

Comment: Are you still maintaining this ?